# In 脱衣, can I put an adjective between it?

Tags: word

Can I use it into 脱我的衣 脱黄衣 脱这衣 although it's 离合词 and 衣 can't stand alone?

Comment: 脱衣 already means "take off one's clothes". It does not seem to be a  离合词.

Comment: But 衣 can't be stand alone

Comment: And in back of it, I can't use a object

Comment: I wanna just know 脱衣, not 脱衣服

Comment: 脱衣 means "take off one's clothes" (see bkrs, ichacha), not sure what "can't be stand alone means", 衣 does seem to "stand alone", also if  v+o is a 离合词 then object certainly can "stand alone"，e.g.毕业，见面， also note 脱衣服，e.g.  脱红衣服，脱孩子的衣服

Comment: No 面 can't stand alone

Comment: bkrs: 初次见面 meet for the first time
他们多年没见面了。 They haven't seen each other for years.; It's many years since they parted.

Comment: I mean 面 can't stand alone as in 面很帅

Answer (score 0, accepted):

脱衣 seems to be a set, not a 离合词.

But 见面 is a 离合词. You could say 见上一面（meet once）；连面也没见(even unable to meet once)；